Confused on how the proof of Monotone Convergence Theorem proves convergence
Self learner here. This is the typical proof for the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Typically the pattern I've seen for proving convergence is based on the epsilon delta definition of a limit L of an infinite sequence where the trick is to find the right value of N and then use that to prove that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.  This proof doesn't seem to follow this approach to me because N is never really defined in the proof, so that's why I am confused. Thank you in advance for your answer.

The author did find a value of N. Namely, given any $\epsilon >0$, there is $a_N$ such that $a_N> \sup_n a_n -\epsilon$. Note also that in the definition of limit, one is not required to be able to give an explicit formula for $N$, just that $N$ exists is good enough.

It is not always necessary that $N$ to be defined explicitly. Since the sequence is increasing there is no pattern in the way the sequence increasing. So its not possible to find $N$ explicitly unless we use the definition of supremum.

@Andrew So N is the index of the term in the sequence that is greater than $sup_n(a_n) - \epsilon$?

${\color{SkyBlue} N}$ is an integer s.t. $a_N>s-\epsilon$. For this ${\color{SkyBlue} N}$, if $n>{\color{SkyBlue} N}$, then $-\epsilon<0\le s-a_n\le s-a_N<\epsilon$, justifying $|s-a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>{\color{SkyBlue} N}$.
